# Indicate if objects after collision will stick

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, collision

Is it possible to indicate if objects after collision will stick together knowing their properties(materials,hardness,etc)?

Answer (score 1):

They will stick together if the collision is inellastic, which means you dissipate the maximum kinetic energy possible, while conserving momentum.
As you might expect, metals, rubber, plastics, etc. all provide a partially elastic collision, since they are rigid.

If the collision speed is high enough, the materials could always fuse (given that the objects don't disintegrate), but I think that is not what you are asking.

As such, I'd say Play-dough-like materials would do the trick (i.e., easily deformable, as the deformation easily dissipates energy as heat), or 'artifically' induced sticking: such as velcro.

Comment: Maybe "mechanically" rather than "artifically"; A hasp or hook works principally the same way. And don't forget glue and even surface tension etc. (in case of small objects) with *chemical* bonding.